# Find second smallest integer (python)

Tags: python, sorting

Are there any other ways than sort() to find the second smallest integer in this row:

```
10 12 2 5 15
```

Comment: `sorted('10 12 2 5 15'.split(),reverse=True)[1]`

Comment: sorting is definately not the best way to do this anyway, as it sorts the whole list - which is wasteful.

Comment: @will Unless you evaluate the performance for your exact use case and find out that surprisingly it is the most efficient way.

Comment: When sorting is or isn't more efficient is irrelevant, because the question asks for alternatives to sorting.

Comment: @moooeeeep without sorting, you only need to traverse the list once, so if the list is long, then sorting it and taking the second entry is going to be a bad technique. How long it needs to be for this to happen depends on the relative speeds, `sort()` is written in `c` though, so it takes a while before a python implementation takes over. For a `random.shuffle()`'d `range(length)` list, on my machine at least, it has to be around 200000 elements long before a naive pure python approach beats it.

Comment: @chepner, i know, but i thought i might point it out to Hackaholic.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`heapq.nsmalles`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest)  :

```
>>> import heapq
>>> l=[10, 12, 2, 5 ,15]
>>> print(heapq.nsmallest(2, l)) [1]
5
```

The most important feature of a heap is that `heap[0]` is always the smallest item. More‐
over, subsequent items can be easily found using the `heapq.heappop()` method, which
pops off the first item and replaces it with the next smallest item (an operation that
requires O(log N) operations where N is the size of the heap)

The `nlargest()` and `nsmallest()` functions are most appropriate if you are trying to
find a relatively small number of items. If you are simply trying to find the single smallest
or largest item (N=1), it is faster to use `min()` and `max()` . Similarly, if N is about the
same size as the collection itself, it is usually faster to sort it first and take a slice (i.e.,
use `sorted(items)[:N]` or `sorted(items)[-N:]` ). It should be noted that the actual
implementation of `nlargest()` and `nsmallest()` is adaptive in how it operates and will
carry out some of these opti`mizations on your behalf (e.g., using sorting if N is close to
the same size as the input).
(reference : *python cookbook 3rd edition*)